# Compute the sum of the positive numbers in a list in Python

Tags: python, sum

Studying for a test...this may be a question but I am stuck and can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```py
def theSum(aList):
    s = 0 
    for x in aList:
        if x > 0:
            s+=x
    return theSum
```

Comment: Assuming 'S' define outside the function?

Comment: Also, you are returning 'thesum' which is not defined in the function and the indentation for variables 'thesum' and 'S' is wrong

Comment: I edited it...s will start at 0. So if i have a list [-1,1,-2,2] the answer I want to compute is 3...2+1.

Comment: You may do `sum(x for x in aList if x > 0)`... Edit: Malik was faster than I...

Comment: Beat you by a second, I did nearly the same thing but with a list comprehension.

Comment: @MaxwellEichberg You need to return 'S' not the 'theSum'. In addition you need to indent the return and the line after the if statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic seems correct but you have a couple of indentation and variable errors in your code.

Instead of returning function itself, you should return `s`:

```
def theSum(aList):
    s = 0 
    for x in aList:
       if x > 0:
           s = s + x
    return s
```

---

```
>>> print theSum([-1, 1, -2, 2])
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You also have the option of using sum:
list=[]
number=input("Enter a list of numbers separated by , \n")
user_list = number.split(',')
for i in range(len(user_list)):
    user_list[i]=int(user_list[i])
print(f"user list is {user_list} ")
if i>0
    sum_list = sum(user_list)
print(sum_list)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).